# Facing issue while installing jq in centos

Tags: centos, jq

While installing jq on centos, I am experiencing an issue. I have run the following commands:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install autoconf automake libtool python
```

after that I have used `pip install jq` and I was facing error like this:

```
jq.c:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
#include "pyconfig.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-akuaZu/jq/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read                                                                                        ().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" 
instal --record /tmp/pip-04CW9h-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally  
-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-akuaZu/jq/
```

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 127):

Just in case if someone is looking for a different solution.

This is how I installed in Cent OS 7 and it worked. Ensure you have **sudo** privilege.

## Installer solution

```
yum install epel-release -y
yum install jq -y
jq --version
```

output was **jq-1.5**

[Reference](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/jq-1.5-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)

Comment: +1 and also you **can't** do `yum install epel-release jq -y`. the epel repository has to be installed first

Comment: This should be the number one answer. Easy manageable with the yum package manager for updates

Comment: Fwiw, with yum I got version 1.3 because older CentOS, but wanted some of the newer functions, so I downloaded the binary jq-1.6 and it seems to work fine under CentOS 6, also. (I am not good at yum and related things..)

Comment: Using this method, I get a very long failure message when I run `yum install jq`.

It ends with: `Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again`

Answer (score 22):

This is how I installed it on CentOS 7:

```
wget https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64 -O jq
chmod +x jq
```

Then

```
mv jq /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Please use `yum` whenever possible.

Comment: @CodeMed `yum` wasn't happening for either the OP or me at the time.

Comment: jq still isn't available via yum as of today.

Answer (score 10):

Install pre-req & install jq

```
$ sudo yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

$ sudo yum install jq -y
```

more usage info..  https://medium.com/@gchandra/install-jq-on-centos-7-459dd650baa3